# upgrade bundler for redmine latest version

Tags: ruby, bundler, redmine

I am trying to upgrade the redmine and for this I have to upgrade the bundler. The strange thing is that the web error show a different version of the bundler that it is installed.

`` Redmine requires Bundler 1.5.0 or higher (you're using 1.3.5).
Please update with 'gem update bundler'. (SystemExit)
  /var/www/redmine-3.2/Gemfile:4:in `abort'
  /var/www/redmine-3.2/Gemfile:4:in `eval_gemfile'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:30:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:30:in `eval_gemfile'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:9:in `evaluate'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:19:in `build'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require' ``

But the version that it is intalled on the server is 1.16.0:

`[root@dev conf.d]# bundle -v
Bundler version 1.16.0`

Comment: Note that bundler 1.16 is currently about the newest released version and thus satisfies the constraint of being newer than 1.5.0 (`16` is larger than `5`)

Comment: you are right. I reformulated the question to show how weird this server is behaving. If you could help me please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
gem update bundler
```

You could also use RVM to manage your versions: https://rvm.io/